# Rails 3 new method route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a scaffold class, now i want to add another method in the controller to it and provide a button link to it to call the method.

How do i do this.

Say the method is called 'new_method', what do i put in the erb and routes files in order to call this get method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose your scaffold class is called `Post`, then in your routes you should have:

```
resources :posts
```

You then want to add a `new_method`, you have to choose whether this will work on the `collection` or on a single object.

#### On a collection

In your routes you write

```
resources :posts do
  collection do
    get :new_method
  end
end
```

And in your `erb` you would write

```
<%= link_to 'Do new-method', new_method_posts_path %>
```

Note, if you want to you could also use `button_to` instead of `link_to` if you prefer to have a button instead.

#### On a single object (member)

In your routes you write

```
resources :posts do
  member do
    get :new_method
  end
end
```

And in your `erb` you would write

```
<%= link_to 'Do new-method', new_method_post_path(@post) %>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi, collections are not working - undefined local variable or method `generate_lunch_place' for #<#<Class:0x274c320>:0x274a970> method is working if i type the path, how do i bloody add the link in the erb? arrrgggh this is badly built.

Comment: <%= link_to 'generate_lunch', generate_lunch_place_path %> this is in my place/index.html.erb in the routes.rb  Lunch::Application.routes.draw do
 get "places/index"

  resources :places do
    collection do
      get :generate_lunch
    end
  end

Comment: It is a collection, so you should be using the `generate_lunch_places_path`. You can always verify the names of the routes by running `rake routes`.

Answer (score 1):

```
match '/route' => 'controller#method'
```

It also depends; it may be cleaner to add the route as a collection or single resource. The the links below for further info :)

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3/

For example, if you wanted a new routine `/filtered`, you have two options.

```
match '/filtered' => 'products#filtered'
```

In the erb you'd then use `filtered_path` as `link_to`'s action/path parameter.

You could also add it to the product resource mapping.

```
resources :products do
  collection do
    get 'filtered'
  end
end
```

Or:

```
resources :products do
  get 'filtered', :on => :collection
end
```

Either will provide a new path (the names of all your paths are viewable by running the `rake routes` task) called `filtered_products_path`.

Comment: could you explain further please. lets say my controller is Products, created from scaffold so has all the crud stuff. 'my_method' is a new method in Products controller, in show.html.erb of Products i would like to call <%= 'link_to 'my method' products_path ectect %>

Comment: Well, you wouldn't want `products_path` there. I'll edit my answer a little.

Comment: product_path is in my erb file.

Comment: `link_to 'Link text', filtered_path` (`match`-style path) or `link_to 'Link text', filtered_products_path` if a resource collection. Really, though, you need to read and understand the documentation links provided--what if I'm wrong? What if you need further info or want to add additional paths?

Answer (score 0):

Please see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions
this will direct you to the solution.

Comment: those links tell you how to add routes but not how to call them from the html.erb file?

Answer (score 0):

Lets call the controller HomeController for this answer. Lets create a view file called `new_method.html.erb`. In the routes.rb create a route like this:

```
match 'new_method' => 'home#new_method'
```

I hope this will work.